# macOS zsh completion for subcommands

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, zsh-completion

I have a script called `,` that takes a finite set of subcommands. Let's say this set is `(foo bar qux)`. So the following are the acceptable CLI invocations this script:

- `, foo`
- `, bar`
- `, qux`

(Each of the above may take further optional arguments to the right).

What is the *minimal* zsh completion code for this script that will work on macOS? Such that when I type `,`  followed by `<TAB>`, the shell will autocomplete with those three options: foo, bar, and qux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the **minimal** steps for adding `zsh` completion to your `,` command:

1. Enabling `compinit`

   ```bash
   autoload -U compinit
   ```
2. Enabling `compdef`

   ```bash
   compinit
   ```
3. Defining a function for completing the first argument from/with a given set of values.

   ```bash
   _,() { _arguments -C '1: :(foo bar qux)'; }
   ```
4. Setting the previous function `_,` as the completion function of the `,` command:

   ```bash
   compdef _, ,
   ```

Now if you type <kbd>Comma</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `zsh` should output:

```
bar  foo  qux
```

---

###### ASIDE

It's possible to add further completion to each sub-command `bar`/`foo`/`qux`; take a look at this documented [example](https://blog.mads-hartmann.com/2017/08/06/writing-zsh-completion-scripts.html#example-completion-script).

Comment: Thanks! That "aside" is also helpful. Specifically I'd wish to *delegate* completion to the respective command. For example, `, git` should delegate to git's autocompletion. I can open a separate question for it if necessary.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar I tried to call the completion function of `git` from inside `_,` but it segfaults zsh!! I think it's worth to ask an other question for it.